# What is the result of following SQL Query?

Tags: sql, join

The SQL query

```
 SELECT columns 
 FROM TableA RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
      TableB 
      ON A.columnName = B.columnName 
 WHERE A.columnName IS NULL
```

returns the following:

(a) All rows in Table B, which meets equality condition above and, none from Table A, which meets the condition

(b) All rows in Table A, which meets equality condition above and none from Table B, which meets the condition

(c) All rows in Table B, which meets equality condition

(d) All rows in Table A, which meets equality condition

What should be the answer ?

Comment: That's called an "anti-join".

Comment: Why don't you google Right outer join or better still, build a test set of data using a sql fiddle sort of site and see what happens when you write that script.

Comment: Simply create the tables, insert some data and see what happens!

Comment: Is that a homework question? If so, you should try to solve it yourself and then ask about the specific problem you're having. (See [point 3 here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic))

Comment: Tip: all options a, b, c, and d are wrong.

Comment: Explain what you think is the answer & why, using references to your textbook or other reference. Otherwise you are just asking us to write yet another presentation of how SQL works with a bespoke tutorial. See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1):

All shown options are wrong. The answer would be:

e) All rows from TableB which "columnName" value is not present in TableA.

Example:

```
create table a (col int);
create table b (col int);

insert into a (col) values (null), (1), (2);
insert into b (col) values (null), (1), (3);

select a.col as a_col, b.col as b_col
from a 
right outer join b on a.col = b.col
where a.col is null
```

Result:

```
a_col   b_col
------  ------
<null>  <null>
<null>       3
```

Comment: +10  anti-join returns all rows from b where there is not a matching row found in a

Answer (score 1):

Answers (b) and (d) are totally wrong.  The query won't return any rows from TableA.

If there are any matching rows are found in TableA, those rows get excluded by the condition in the WHERE clause. (Note that any value of `columnName` that satisfies the equality comparison in the ON clause will be non-NULL, and that value will not satisfy the "IS NULL" condition in the WHERE clause.)

Answer (c) is also wrong. The query will return rows from TableB for which there is no matching row found in TableA.

The least wrong answer is (a) ... but it is still wrong in that the choice of words does not accurately convey the definition of the set.

---

The query is an *anti-join* pattern.

The query defines a set of rows found in TableB which do not have a matching row in TableA.

Another way of specifying that set is with a NOT EXISTS condition with a correlated subquery:

```
 SELECT b.*
   FROM tableB b
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
        ( SELECT 1
            FROM tableA a
           WHERE a.columnName = b.columnName )
```